# CRIT 002 Failed to initialize local MSP: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, erc20

I try this toutorial https://github.com/grepruby/ERC20-Token-On-Hyperledger

```
node: v8.11.4
go: go1.12.6 darwin/amd64
hyperledgerfabric: ? (maybe 1.2.1)
Python3.4
```

When './buildERC20TokenNetwork.sh up' command executed, the error occur.

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.techracers.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

detail

```
./buildERC20TokenNetwork.sh up
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] Y
proceeding ...
./buildERC20TokenNetwork.sh: line 46: /Users/ogasawara/hyperledger-fabric/ERC20-Token-On-Hyperledger/network/../bin/configtxlator: cannot execute binary file
LOCAL_VERSION=
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2.1
=================== WARNING ===================
  Local fabric binaries and docker images are  
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.       
===============================================
peer1.org2.techracers.com is up-to-date
Starting orderer.techracers.com ... 
peer0.org2.techracers.com is up-to-date
peer1.org1.techracers.com is up-to-date
Starting orderer.techracers.com ... done
cli is up-to-date

 ____    _____      _      ____    _____ 
/ ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|
\___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |  
 ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ <    | |  
|____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|  


Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
+ peer channel create -o orderer.techracers.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/techracers.com/orderers/orderer.techracers.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.techracers.com-cert.pem
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.techracers.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Docker container "orderer.techracers.com" is Exited, that causes the connection failer.
I checked docker cantainer log.

```
initializeLocalMsp -> CRIT 002 Failed to initialize local MSP: could not load a valid signer certificate from directory /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: stat /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/signcerts: no such file or directory
```

How can I up the container "orderer.techracers.com" ?

Comment: The problem is that I used Python3.x.
After I change Python3.x to Python 2.x, the problem was solved.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the real error is further up:

`./buildERC20TokenNetwork.sh: line 46: /Users/ogasawara/hyperledger-fabric/ERC20-Token-On-Hyperledger/network/../bin/configtxlator: cannot execute binary file`

So either you do not have the binaries installed or they are not where they are expected.

(I would guess that the error you are seeing with the orderer is because the config hasn't been properly set up beforehand.)

Fabric 1.2.1 is quite dated now, you might be better starting off with Fabric 1.4 and working with the samples that come with Fabric and the standard documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try Fabric 1.4